# Compiler not recognising class member function type in implementation file but recognised in interface file

Tags: c++, class, struct, directx-11, return-type

As part of a class that I've created I have a struct representing a constant buffer. In the interface file (.h file) there is a getter function whose return type is the same as that of the struct. The function prototype in the .h file is recognised fine by the compiler, however in the implementation file (.cpp file) in the function definition the compiler is underlining the return type of the function in red, saying that it is undefined. The header file is included in the .cpp file so I am unsure why the return type of the function isn't recognised. Here is the code:

For the header file:

```
#ifndef _PLAYERCLASS_H_
#define _PLAYERCLASS_H_

//Std library includes
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>

// include the Direct3D Library file
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")

class PlayerClass
{
private:

// a struct to define the constant buffer
struct CBUFFER
{
    D3DXMATRIX Final;
    D3DXMATRIX Rotation;
    D3DXVECTOR4 LightVector;
    D3DXCOLOR LightColor;
    D3DXCOLOR AmbientColor;
};

public:

//Functions
PlayerClass();        //Constructor
~PlayerClass();       //Destructor

//Functions to set up player

//Getters
CBUFFER constBuff();                    //Return the constant buffer 

//Setters



private:

//Some private member variables

//Constant buffer to contain alterations to player etc
CBUFFER pUpdates;


};

#endif
```

For the .cpp file:

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <Windows.h>
PlayerClass::PlayerClass()
{
    pUpdates.LightVector = D3DXVECTOR4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    pUpdates.LightColor = D3DXCOLOR(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    pUpdates.AmbientColor = D3DXCOLOR(0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f);

}

PlayerClass::~PlayerClass()
{

}

void PlayerClass::initPlayer()
{

}

CBUFFER PlayerClass::constBuff()
{
    return pUpdates;
}
```

The function that is not being recognised is the last function specifically the CBUFFER part which is underlined in red.

Comment: Try `PlayerClass::CBUFFER PlayerClass::constBuff()`

Comment: That did it - may I ask why it wan't being recognised? Thanks by the way.

Comment: Because `CBUFFER` is part of `PlayerClass`, you have to declare it the same way you declare your `PlayerClass` functions in the src file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `CBUFFER` is in the scope of the `PLayerClass`. With an old-fashioned C++03 function definition like your

```
CBUFFER PlayerClass::constBuff()
{
    return pUpdates;
}
```

the name `CBUFFER` is looked up in the enclosing namespace, and not found.

You can either play the game of qualifications, like

```
PlayerClass::CBUFFER PlayerClass::constBuff()
{
    return pUpdates;
}
```

or, be (IMO) smart about it, and adopt a single more easy on the eye syntax for all function definitions, and write

```
auto PlayerClass::constBuff()
    -> CBUFFER
{
    return pUpdates;
}
```

where, when the `CBUFFER` name is encountered, the compiler knows that it's in a member function definition, and therefore looks up the name also in the class.

---

In other news, class name prefixes like `CPlayer` and suffixes like `PlayerClass` do not add any relevant information. They only add more to write and more to read. So why not name the class `Player`. Also, ALL UPPERCASE is an eyesore, and conflicts with common naming convention for macros (as well as with the Java/Python convention for constants). So why not call that e.g. `Buffer` – or something more self-descriptive, perhaps.

Comment: Hello - yes thank you for pointing out the use of the auto keyword, didn't know of its usage implications until now. Will also bear in mind the naming convention of the class.